# /INCREMENTAL linking option ignored is vs2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

After updating project from vs2015 to vs2019, the same build option doesn't give the same result =(
The /EDITANDCONTINUE linking option was working but not anymore...

[image: Screenshot from build]

Comment: If you can reproduce or provide an example, VS has a bug report system for such problem. It's not for SO.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a bug report for MS/VS not SO.

Comment: Your warnings seem to be about mixing CRTs. Looks like one if them is about using a debug CRT in the release configuration. This could  be an indication of undefined behavior as debug and release runtimes are incompatible.

Comment: After display the link output in verbose mode, i saw that he ovveride the /INCREMENTAL by /INCREMENTAL:NO when it check the embedded libs. Some of them are not build with the /INCREMENTAL so it can't keep the /INCREMENTAL for my project.
The project has not change, the same libs were embedded in the vs2015 solution too...